# Make ArcGIS Desktop 10.5 Developer Console Window Appear?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.5

Long ago, on an older machine, with an older form of ArcGIS Desktop (10.4), I was able to make the console window appear upon startup for all local ArcGIS Desktop applications (ArcMap, Catalog, etc).
It did not matter:

- which language or IDE used
- if debugging or no

I could see my logs immediately.

Now on a newer machine, with 10.5, I cannot figure this out. I would like to set Desktop10.5 so that my console window appears upon startup for my desktop applications.

(See the image as the example, in ArcMap10.4, of what I'm trying to accomplish in 10.5 setup.)
[image: example: console window automatically appears when opening ArcMap]

I've searched around in:
C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.5\bin

I'm just not finding what I'm looking for, or any documentation for this.

Answer (score 0):

To consistently produce a console window for your ArcGIS Desktop applications, the key is to use the Java Configuration Tool (JCT), found in:

ArcGIS\Desktop10.x\bin

Right-click and "Run as administrator."

Select "Create console window for ArcGIS applications (ArcMap/ArcCatalog)"

[image]

Click "Apply." Restart your machine for the new settings to be applied.

Then, every time you open ArcMap or ArcCatalog, debugging or not, a console window will appear.

[image]

see also:

https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcobjects/latest/java/#5ea8aa1a-0b3e-46c1-8589-757bdc50d4d1.htm